# Grouping (not ordering) objects into alphabetical list on a single Django page

Tags: django, django-views

I’m trying to display a list of objects in an alphabetic list for a directory page. Something that looks like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_and_television_directors

To avoid having to click on the link, the list would be:

**Surname starts with A**

• Anderson, Wes

**Surname starts with B**

• Burton, Tim

**Surname starts with C**

• Coppola, Sofia

A simplified version of the model would be:

```
class Person(model.Models):
     first_name = model.CharField
     last_name = model.CharField

     def __str__(self):
          return "{}, {}".format(self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

**Route 1. In the view?**

If not filtering in the template, after that I thought it would be possible to filter the objects within the view and send each portion separately.

```
def person_list(request):
     startswith_a = Person.objects.filter(last_name__startswith="a")
     startswith_b = Person.objects.filter(last_name__startswith="b")
     startswith_c = Person.objects.filter(last_name__startswith="c")
     etc.
     etc.
     return render(request, "directory/person-list.html", {"startswith_a": startswith_a, "startswith_b": startswith_b})
```

But that feels wrong as I’d have to hard code the alphabet into the view definition, and then pass all 26 (or more) sets into the view.

**Route 2. In the model?**

Finally I thought it might be possible to have a new field in the model which would affix its location in the directory. This could be updated manually or (I guess?) by customising the save function on the model to automatically assign based on the first character of the last_name field.

```
class Person(model.Models):
     directory_position = model.CharField  # eg. "a"
     first_name = model.CharField # eg. "Wes"
     last_name = model.CharField # eg. "Anderson"

     def __str__(self):
          return "{}, {}".format(self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

With that set, it would be possible to use template tags to show the relevant objects in each portion of the page.

```
{{ person.directory_position="a" }}
```

But that still feels a bit hacky because the template would have to iterate over the whole returned list for each of the 26 characters (and more for special characters).

Again, I feel like I must be missing something obvious. There’s probably a single line of code that will do all of this (especially in Python!) but I just can’t figure it out.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why you are not considering doing it directly in the template?

Comment: Just in case if you decide to go with the template solution: check regroup tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup